# Gantt diagram issue

Tags: algorithms

Given a Gantt diagram, how would you calculate the minimum time for two workers to complete the whole project. Part i) of the question was how long would it take for one person, which is the sum of all events, but two workers is confusing the hell out of me, do I need to go through it manually or is there a short cut as obviously it isn't just the net time divided by two as there are lag times between some.

Comment: Depends on the diagram, on the operations, if the two workers work together in one same operation, if one worker works in one operation meanwhile the other works in another. Can you show it?

Comment: Its actually an exam question, http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MD02-P-QP-JUN15.PDF , If you'd like I can draw the gantt diagram got it